# Detect compatible versions of Internet Explorer for dropzone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, dropzone.js

Dropzone.js says that it [supports](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#compatibility) Internet Explorer versions 10+. I'm not really worried about browsers other than Internet Explorer being too old.

How should I detect whether the browser is compatible with dropzone? Should I detect it by its features (which is what some people say about browser compatibility), or by checking the version of the browser, and if so, how?

(I'm using Rails, if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry too much about this - Dropzonejs adds automatically file input element if it detects an incompatible browser version.